# Using cUrl with android on devices with different architectures

Tags: android, curl, android-ndk

I would like to use native library cUrl in my android project, but i'm afraid that there could be problems with different architectures. 
I'm new to NDK, so it would be great, if you'll help  me with that question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to include a native library in your Android application, you need to build it for all possible architectures like arm, x86. If you don't your application won't work on devices that you don't provide builds for and also they won't be visible in Google Play for those devices. However within those architecture builds you are safe.

Android NDK provides all the necessary support to get you covered in this scenario, so you should start from reading there.

Comment: @renal if you intend to build it for multiple architectures, these steps (written for [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/)) might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13849821/1688185. Also feel free to refer to these [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/deltheil/running-native-code-on-android-number-osdcfr-2012).