# GSL: nm outputs "undefined Symbol (U)"

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling, gsl

I cross compiled gsl fro `android` using `arm-linux-androideabi`. When I dynamically loaded this library in `android-studio`, it gave me error.

> can not locate symbol cblas_sdsdot.

I ran `nm` command on gsl and got

> U cblas_sdsdot

Then I ran `nm` command on gslcblas and got

> 000002645 T cblas_sdsdot.

I also loaded `gslcblas.so` before `gsl.so` but still I am getting the error. Any suggestion to get rid of this problem? Thanks

Comment: Check that you have path to `.so` files in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` , or library search path in `android-studio`.  And reload it , try to run `ldd gsl` and check on what libraries it's linked

Comment: There is path to all the `.so` files present in my project and also i did `readelf -d` to check the dependencies and it gave me `libm.so` , `libc.so`, `libdl.so` and `libgsl.so.0`. this last `libgsl.so.0` is also present in the same folder.The folder is `/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/`. Any other suggestion? I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also in `andrioid-studio` terminal.

Comment: can you use ldd ? it will print exact libs what file looking for

Comment: Actually my system is `64bit` and `ldd` is giving `not a dynamic executable` output. So i used `readelf` and it gave me 'libm.so' , 'libc.so', 'libdl.so' and 'libgsl.so.0'.